# Use interface with DI and @Creatable in E4 application

Tags: java, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

Now with the `@Creatable` annotation is possible to mark a class to be injected without adding it in the `EclipseContext` by hand in the life cycle:

http://blog.vogella.com/2012/02/29/eclipse-4-is-now-a-full-dependency-injection-container-with-creatable/

However, what about the following scenario: lets say that I have an interface `SomethingService` and some number of implementations, and I want to refer to one of those (i.e. the one annotated as creatable) by its interface, something like:

```
@Creatable
class Todo implements SomethingService {
    @Inject
    public Todo(SomeArg arg) {
    // placeholder
    }
 }

 // Field Injection
 @Inject private SomethingService service;  // Todo instance
```

This doesn’t seem to work at all. Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Do you have `SomeArg` in the Eclipse context so that it can be found? Eclipse only does injection on objects that the application model knows about (parts, handlers...).

Comment: Yes, it is. It was just an example, if I use an empty constructor the result is the same.

Comment: What class are you trying to inject SomethingService in to, as I said this must be something that the application model knows about - otherwise no injection is done and you get null.

Comment: Yes, I'm injecting the SometingService into a Part from the Application.e4xmi
In fact, another things are injected correctly, like Declarative Services or the Event Broker. And if I change the "SomethingService service" to "Todo service" it works.

Answer (score 4):

Well, from what I could see what I'm asking should be done with the OSGi Declarative Services or like the example from "Eclipse 4 Plug-in Development by Example" modifying the Activator like this:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws 
        InjectorFactory.getDefault().
           addBinding(IStringService.class).implementedBy(StringService.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Were there some advancements on this topic, or does it still work like that?